# LocalDateTime converter and null value

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot, with spring jpa, hibernate and java 8

In some entity i have some **LocalDateTime** datatype.

In Db for these fiels that occur that have some null value.

I get this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   org.springframework.data.convert.Jsr310Converters$DateToLocalDateTimeConverter.convert(Jsr310Converters.java:100)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RC2.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten.Jsr310JpaConverters$LocalDateTimeConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(Jsr310JpaConverters.java:88)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RC2.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten.Jsr310JpaConverters$LocalDateTimeConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(Jsr310JpaConverters.java:78)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RC2.jar:na]   at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$2.doConversion(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:139)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$2.extract(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:120)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]

Comment: looks like Spring's converters don't allow for null!! pretty basic requirement IMHO

Comment: i was supported before a few week ago... converter is used automatically so how to avoir to call converter is value is null

Comment: I got stuck with the same problem. Any solution for this?

My field is allowed to be null, defined by column annotation and table definition. But i also get this nullpointerexception. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Jsr310Converters is not needed anymore with spring boot 2.

Comment: That's not a very helpful answer for anyone using Spring Boot 1.x (which I'm pretty sure your question is based on).

Comment: no my question is for spring boot 2, spring boot 1.x it's old

Comment: Could you share, what you've done to get it running with LocalDate(Time) when it's null?